# How do we extend a React Native "form" component, the type that takes user input?

Tags: react-native, components

I can find surprisingly little documentation, tutorials, or examples, of how to make my own reusable React Native component based on an existing component.

Of the ones I can find, none seem to be extending components such as `Picker` that "returns" input from the user.

Even looking at the source code for Native Base's Picker is not straightforward. For instance it seems to define the Picker's `Item` in two different places. Some of the stuff that looks like glue or boilerplate I don't understand at all either, even though there's only a couple of lines of it.

How can I extend an "input" component, or where is an example I can follow?

Answer (score 1):

Because React Native is just one rendering target for React, lot of the basic documentation exists in the [React core library docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/). If you're just beginning React Native and haven't worked with React on the web, those docs are a good place to start.

See specifically: [Composition vs Inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Similarly, when googling how to do something with React Native that isn't specific to the native rendering target, you're often better of googling for just "react".

To answer your question, in React, the typical way of extending components is to wrap them in another component:

```
const EmailInput = props => {
  return (
    <TextInput 
      keyboardType="email-address"
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      {...props}
    />
  )
}
```

You can then use this component just like you do TextInput, e.g

```
<EmailInput value={this.state.value} />
```

As a sidenote, I have also found it tricky to extend components in NativeBase, but those are issues related to some of the design decisions made in the NativeBase library, and not generic to React.

Comment: So I think I see that you're passing an initial `value` from `EmailInput` to `Input`. What about getting the string input by the user back? Another thing a good example I'd like to find would show is the derived component can have its own properties and the base component properties and how the calling code uses those. You're right I am using React for the first time via React Native and I have started going straight to React docs since posting this question. I'm actually catching up with a bunch of new concepts at once after years away from software dev.

Comment: The value is a bit more than just an initial value - it is the value binding, see Controlled Components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components -- and to pass pass values back, you'd use callback props. But I believe this is all in the docs. Good luck! :)